# How to replace first and last 4 bytes in binary file in python

Tags: python, file, binary

This should be easy!

I have a binary file. and I need to read the first 4 bytes from the file and replace the value there. 
for example: if the first 4 bytes is 00000000 so I want to replace them with 11111111.

Also I need to read the last 4 bytes of the file and replace the value there. 
please note that file size should not be changed. only replace bits we need.

Comment: Show us what you tried already. What didn't work?

Comment: In case my new value is "7631231B" and I want to write it in the last 4 bytes how we can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work in python 2.7:

```
with open(filepath, 'r+b') as f:
    data = f.read(4)
    f.seek(0)
    if len(somestring) != 4:
        raise ValueError
    f.write(somestring)
    f.seek(os.path.getsize(filepath)-4)
    enddata = f.read(4)
    f.seek(os.path.getsize(filepath)-4)
    if len(endstring) != 4:
        raise ValueError
    f.write(endstring)
```

Comment: my bad, meant to write the strings without quotations, sorry

Comment: How we make sure that f.write(somestring) replace the "old" 4 bytes data exactly?  - I mean to overlap the first 4 bytes only

Comment: Now it verifies that it is 4 characters

Comment: with open(FIF_NAME, 'r+b') as f:
        # data = f.read(4)
        f.seek(0)
        new_val = '11111111'
        if len(new_val) != 4:
            raise ValueError
        f.write(new_val)


we get exception

Comment: Because my friend '11111111' is an 8 byte string and not a 4 byte string, each 1 is a character in ascii (char 49) and is a byte on its own

Comment: Worked!
regarding last 4 bytes:
In case my new value is 7631231B and I want to write it in the last 4 bytes
how we can do it?